# What is the Exact Definition of Maximal Forest

Tags: graph-theory

I was trying to prove a problem of Bondy Murthy Graph Theory book, i've seen the `Maximal Forest`

the problem was :

> Let G be a graph and F a maximal forest of G. Show that $E(F) = V(G) − C(G).$

where `C(G)` is the number of `cycles` of Graph `G`, and `V(G)` is the number of vertices in Graph `G`, and `E(F)` is the Number of Edges which are in the Maximal Forest `F`

I have two idea about `Maximal Forest`, i don't know if they are true or not :

1 - Assume that the graph needs to be **Connected** and we need to find a tree, the problem would be like `Minimum Spanning Tree` and the number of Edges would be Equal to `V(G)-1`, which is not the satisfy the formula of the problem, for example we can imagine a empty graph

2 - Assuming that graph is **not Connected**, so it has different partitions and the could have cycles or not(which means they could have tree like structure or not), so what is the definition of `Maximal Forest` here ? if we want to make a forest of it we can remove the cycles in each partition, this could satisfy the formula `E(F) = V(G) - C(G)`, but i can't see any kind of `Maximal` in this forest, it is just a **Normal** Forest

i would appreciate any help. i really need to know the exact definition of `Maximal Forest`

Comment: Shouldn't $C(G)$ here mean the number of connected components of $G$?

Comment: @Joppy i have no idea, but seems you are right, the problem has nothing more

Comment: @joppy with your defintion i can prove that problem, but the main problem is still remaining, what is `Maximal Forest` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the formula, they clearly mean that a maximal forest of $G$ consists of a set of spanning trees for each component in $G$.

*Edit: I notice that you misinterpreted $C(G)$ as the number of cycles of $G$, when it should actually be the number of connected components of $G$.*

So for a connected $G$, the maximal forest would just be a spanning tree, $C(G)=1$ and the formula is good.

In the case of the empty graph, $V(G)=C(G)=0$ so the formula again holds.

Comment: thanks for your answer, my problem is with the defintion of `Maximal Graph`, for example a `Complete Graph` like `K4` has 6 edges and it is connected to, it has `C(G) != 1`

Comment: The number of components $C(G)$ of a complete graph certainly is $1$... A maximal forest (= spanning tree) for $K_4$ would have $V(G)-C(G)=4-1 =3 $ edges as expected

Comment: thank you, i've proved the problem